# Php-MySql Query , Selecting Data According to DateTime

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, select

I would like to get number of rows that have same date. But one second must be negligible.

For example ; 2012-01-03 13:12:28 and 2012-01-03 13:12:27 should be perceived as the same.

( I have a table name is `myTable` and the datetime column name is `date` )

I hope you will help me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's as simple as:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE date >= '2012-01-03 13:12:27' AND date <= '2012-01-03 13:12:28';
```

If you want to build it up from a variable, you could do this:

```
$date = '2012-01-03 13:12:27';
$timestamp = strtotime($date);
$mysqli = new mysqli();

// Note: allowing 1 second either side, this is up to you
$lower = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp - 1);
$upper = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp + 1);

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE date >= ? AND date <= ?');
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $lower, $upper);
$stmt->execute();
```

**EDIT**: As per your comment below, the following SQL should return what you're after. Note that if a date contains '2012-01-03 13:12:28' it will be counted for both :27 and :28.

```
SELECT
    upper_date,
    COALESCE(lower_count, 0) + upper_count
FROM
    (SELECT
        date AS upper_date,
        COUNT(1) AS upper_count
    FROM myTable
    GROUP BY date
    ) AS upper
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
        date - INTERVAL 1 SECOND AS lower_date,
        COUNT(1) AS lower_count
    FROM myTable
    GROUP BY date
    ) AS lower
ON upper.upper_date = lower.lower_date
```

Comment: But, I don't know dates in my table. I would like to learn number of rows that have similar date (according to year-month-day-hour-minute )

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p1.date, p1.sex, p2.date, p2.sex, p1.species ......
        FROM table_name AS p1, table_name AS p2
        WHERE p1.date-p2.species in(0,1);
```

For such cases we use self join of a table with aliases...and as your condition is the difference between the dates should not be more than 1 here it goes...

I presume that you have stored date as mysql datetime...to perform "-" operation..

Answer (score 0):

Try this once:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM myTable
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') = '2012-01-03 13:12';
```

Or for a group-related COUNT:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') as myDate, count(*)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY myDate;
```

Comment: I think you don't even need to DATE_FORMAT the field, you can just use `WHERE DATE('2012-01-03 01:01:01') = DATE(my_date)` for every row that is on 2012 01 03.

Comment: Nice @kontur, I just tried that on my local and it worked.  That's a viable alternative for my first query.

Comment: You might also like `WHERE DATE(NOW()) = myDate` to check, for instance, for today, or with DATE_ADD, for x days from today - just on a sidenote ,)

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to count number of rows per date it would be simple GROUP BY:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d') as my_date
  FROM myTable
  GROUP BY my_date
```

But by your question you are not only need to count rows within a date, but also count not a single events but it's series. In this case you will need to define what exactly series are. Say two events within one second should be counted as one. What if there are four events with 0.7 distance between each other? In this case I would suggest to count series in two steps.

First - order events by time:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE date >= XXXX and date < YYYY ORDER BY date ASC
```

Then on the application side you can count the gap between two records and increase counter if distance between two close events is more than one second.

Don't forget to add index on `date` field to speed up this query.