# Select all dates after a certain date

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get all dates after a given date in MySQL, but the results are the exact opposite of what I want.

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(DRFDate) FROM tblDRF WHERE DRFDate > $DepartureDate";
```

But this is giving me all the dates *before* $DepartureDate

Comment: could you add sql to reproduce the issue ?

Comment: If you are using PHP, use parameterized query like https://stackoverflow.com/a/8717558/2554537 or https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/select

Answer (score 1):

Your need to put `$DepartureDate` in a single quote.

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(DRFDate) FROM tblDRF WHERE DRFDate > '$DepartureDate'";
```